# issue with IIS 7 for website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, c#-3.0

I have hosted website on IIS 7. All are working well but after some times website not render well like it shows title but not shows content or it shows some content but not full. I try to solve at iis level like I changes Application Pool to classic etc. But I have not get any full resolution of issue. Please help me.

Comment: Then you need to reproduce the issue, and capture HTTP packets or analyze IIS logs for hints first.

Comment: I have seen log files and it gives 2012-02-07 06:10:22 216.107.30.16 GET / - 80 - 117.212.210.70 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+5.1;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.25)+Gecko/20111212+Firefox/3.6.25 200 0 995 8080

Comment: That means IIS sent out the full response (200). Then you have to rely on network packets to see how the content is lost from the server to your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had replace all files once again. now it is working fine.